# How to rearrange views with iOS Auto Layout

Tags: ios6, xcode4.5, autolayout

I'm trying to wrap my head around auto layout. I think I get it for the most part (probably missing something), but how would i set up the views pictured below?

Without auto layout, I would just test for orientation and then re-set the frames of the blue and purple views (and also the white ones probably). In auto layout, I'm not sure yet how to approach this. Would I need to remove and replace the constraints, so that in top/bottom constraints between these views in portrait orientation, I would have leading/trailing between them in landscape? Or is it easier than that?

[image]
[image]